# How to print plain text when format is decided in the bst and cls file?

Tags: fonts

**Background**

I am writing my thesis for which style, cls and bst files have been provided by the university. As a result, text inputs in certain fields (\author is one such example) are always printed as a bold font. I can change the font size `{\small or  \huge}`, or make it italics `\textit{}` of the text in the \author field. Sample code is as follows:

```
\begin{document}
\title{qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq}
\author{xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx \\\vspace{5mm} {\small Roll no. aaaaaaaaa \\ ID no. bbbbbb \\\vspace{10mm} \textrm{zzzzzzzzz:}}\\\vspace{5mm} \textrm{kkkkkkkkkkk \\mmmmmmmmmmmmm} }
\reporttype{ssssssssssssssss}

\date{\monthyeardate\today}
\dept{\small uuuuuuuuuuuu}

\maketitle
\pagenumbering{roman}
```

[image: screenshot]

**Question**

Which command can be used to remove the bold font?? I can tweak the text in \author field to change the font size or use italics. `\textrm{}` does not remove the bold font.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Maybe `\textrm{}` will work? If not, then you need to expand your question with more information on what the style file is and what fields are printed in bold. Also keep in mind that if you are using a style file for a scientific article for a journal or conference, or for a college assignment, usually it is not allowed to changed the appearance of document elements or the bibliography.

Comment: @Marijn I altered the cls file to remove the bold font related command. How can I mark my question as resolved? Should I delete the question?

Comment: You can provide an answer to your own question in the answer box below. This may help other people that visit the site in the future, especially when they use the same style file as you (i.e., people from your university) but also when they have a related problem and they are looking for a general approach to solve their own problem. If you provide an answer then you should make sure it provides sufficient information, so the name of the style file and the piece of code that you changed (original version and the changes that you made).

Comment: And also don't forget to check with your thesis supervisor if you are allowed to change the formatting of this page.

Comment: @Marijn Thank you for the warning, I would get it approved. As you suggested, I would include a relevant portion of the cls file that I altered along with unaltered code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Following is the maketitle related code in the cls file. I searched for the field name `author`. I noticed that the author field is placed with `\bfseries` command - see second the last line (`{\large  \bfseries \@author \par}`).

**Solution**

I removed the `\bfseries` command and the issue was resolved. Now, the text in the `author` field is normal and not bold.

```
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  {\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\normalsize
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  {\Usefont{ptm}
    \begin{center}
      {\Usefont{phv}\LARGE \bfseries \@title \par}
      \vspace{\stretch{1}}
      \@declaration
      \vspace{\stretch{1}}
      {\large  \bfseries \@author \par}
      \vspace{\stretch{2}}
```

Comment: First: never change a cls file. Second: why bother? The University provides the files, chances are pretty high that they require the bold font.

Comment: Have you considered changing `{\large  \bfseries \@author \par}` to `{\large  {\bfseries \@author} \par}`. That way, the author name is still in bold but the subsequent text is not.

Comment: I have made the author name bold by modifying the main code as follows: `\author{textbf{xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx}`